# sort a list of strings based on the number of occurrences of a given char in the string

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function that will sort a list of strings in ascending order bases on the number of occurrences of a certain character without using any library functions, but i do want to know how i can use my version of inssort to do this i am bit confused any help appreciated

My code so far returns wrong order,

say i give it

sortwords 'c' ["abcc", "abc", "bbc", "aa"]

i want it to return

```
["aa", "abc", "bbc", abcc"]
```

but i get

```
["abc","bbc","aa","abcc"]
```

Here is my code:

```
insert :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insert f a [] = [a]
insert f a (x:xs) = if f a <= f x then a:x:xs else x : insert f a xs  

inssort :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
inssort f [] = []
inssort f [x] = [x]
inssort f (x:xs) = insert f x (inssort f xs)

countocc :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
countocc x [] = 0
countocc x xs = length [x' | x' <- xs, x == x'] 

sortwords :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
sortwords c [] = []
sortwords c [x]= [x]
sortwords c (x:y:ys) = if countocc c x <= countocc c y then x :  sortwords c (y:ys) else y : sortwords c (x:ys)
```

Comment: is there a way i can use my version of insertion sort `inssort` to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I won't spoil the whole solution, but here's a hint: it looks like you are trying to reimplement your sorting procedure in `sortwords`. Don't do that; just reuse `inssort` directly! Try filling in this replacement function skeleton:

```
sortwords :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
sortwords c strings = inssort f strings where
    f s = ...
```

What do you think the `...` should be?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer would you be able to explain to me what \s means i have never used or seen that used before thanks

Comment: even with your hint i am still kinda lost am i able to use countocc within ur skeleton function?

Comment: i had something like this `sortwords c (y:ys) = inssort (countocc c y) (ys)` but i get type errors using this i am just lost to be completely honest

Comment: @Jimbhoy `\ ` introduces an anonymous function. The syntax is, roughly, `\<var> -> <exp>`; this is a function that accepts one argument, names it whatever is in the `<var>` spot, and returns the value of whatever is in the `<exp>` spot. But if you haven't seen it before, no big deal; I'll edit my answer shortly to show an alternative that will likely be closer to your understanding.

Comment: i am still a bit lost not gonna lie this is what i had but its wrong types it says `sortwords c (y:ys) = inssort (countocc c y) (ys)`

Comment: @Jimbhoy This new piece of code, together with the error it produces, and a description of which parts of the error you do understand and which you find confusing (and why), would make an excellent second question to open.

Comment: i am just really confused with how to solve the problem overall, even in your answer `f s = ...` i am not 100% sure i know what this does would i be right in saying that f is the function but i am not sure with what s is

Comment: i know its not the best way but is there anyway you would be willing to post the full solution i just can't get my head around it and have been trying for a while even before i posted this question, if you posted your solution would be much appreciated so i can learn from it and try to understand where i was going wrong thanks

Comment: I really am just lost and don't want to leave this problem on a bad note with no understanding thats why i am asking if you could edit your answer with a full solution so i can better my understanding for the future as i am just trying to learn

Comment: @Jimbhoy `f s = ...` is exactly the same syntax as `sortwords c strings = ...` -- the latter defines a function named `sortwords` that accepts arguments `c` and `strings`, while the former defines a function named `f` that accepts an argument `s`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229365/discussion-between-jimbhoy-and-daniel-wagner).

Comment: i am just my mind is all over the place and i have still no idea despite your great effort to help is there any way you are able to edit your answer with a full solution so i can take a look try get my head around it and understand what you did thanks?